# Finding index in arraylist always coming up at -1

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

Im trying to find the index of student object through their ID attribute through an arraylist. however it always comes up -1.

```
 public int findIndex(String id) {
    // boolean exists = studentArray.contains(id);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.size(); i++) {
        if (studentArray.get(i).getId().equals(id)) {
            return index = studentArray.indexOf(i);
        }
    } return -1;
}
```

However in my demo

```
BodyBag bag = new BodyBag(3);
Student student = new Student("Joe","1234",3.5);
Student student2 = new Student("Jill", "5678",3.4);
Student student3 = new Student("Angelina","9101",4.0);
System.out.println(bag.studentArray.get(0).getId().contains("1234"));
```

actually comes out as true. but in the first class it comes out as false and returns -1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite get `studentArray.indexOf(i);` - wouldn't `i` already be the index? What's `studentArray` anyways? If it is an array as the name suggests, there should be no `indexOf()` method.

Comment: In your demo, you didn't add the new created students into the BodyBag.

Answer (score 2):

You said your goal is

> find the index of student object through their ID attribute through an arraylist

I would recommend you simply implement the [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method within your `Student` class in such a way that it returns true if and only if two `Student` instances have the same `id` and then simply use the [indexOf method provided by ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

The `equals` method in `Student` might look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    return id == null ? other.id == null : id.equals(other.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just return the index(**i**)

```
 return i;
```

Instead of after finding it equals, you again try to find the index of **i** which isn't correct, you should find the index of student by it's id, but you already done it and find it to be at index **i**.

**Note:** Your `index` variable is useless the moment you choose when finding the element not to break the loop, but to return the index.

Answer (score 1):

In your findIndex() method, replace this line

```
          return index = studentArray.indexOf(i);
```

with

```
          return i ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having a conceptual mistake. Actually:

```
studentArray.indexOf( elem );
```

returns the index of the element *elem* in the array, but *elem* should be of the class **Student**. Of course, as long as this class provides an 'equals' method. In your case, something like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals( Object obj ) {
    // first you should check if obj is student before casting it...
    Student aux = (Student) obj;
    return this.getId().equals( aux.getId() );
}
```

What you're doing in your code with the line:

```
return studentArray.indexOf( i );
```

is trying to find an integer (i) in an array of students (studentArray).

Other way to do it, as posted below, is to just return the position, wich is:

```
return i;
```

Cheers.